# Wrong Spotify Track

Tags: ios, spotify

I use the iOS SDK. I have two buttons to play songs

One for Katy Perry's track Fireworks

`appRemote.playerAPI?.play("spotify:track:4lCv7b86sLynZbXhfScfm2") { (restult, error) in }`

Second for Robbie Williams's track Angles

`appRemote.playerAPI?.play("spotify:track:1M2nd8jNUkkwrc1dgBPTJz") { (restult, error) in }`

I switch between them and it works correctly.

But if, for example, Robbie Williams's track ends than new song plays, a Snoop Dog's song for example. I switch to Katy, listen her song to the end, new song starts, a Metallica's song for example. Now when I am trying to switch between Katy and Robbie I switch between Metallica and Snoop Dog.
What have I done wrong?

I have tried: `appRemote.playerAPI?.setRepeatMode(.track) { (restult, error) in }` , but it doesn't help.

The full source:

```
let SpotifyClientID = "xxx"
let SpotifyRedirectURL = URL(string: "xxx://callback")!

class SpotifyManager: NSObject {
    static var shared = SpotifyManager()

    static var playerStateDidChange: (()->())?

    static var configuration = SPTConfiguration(
        clientID: SpotifyClientID,
        redirectURL: SpotifyRedirectURL
    )

    static var sessionManager: SPTSessionManager = {
        if let tokenSwapURL = URL(string: "https://xxx.glitch.me/api/token"),
            let tokenRefreshURL = URL(string: "https://xxx.glitch.me/api/refresh_token") {
            configuration.tokenSwapURL = tokenSwapURL
            configuration.tokenRefreshURL = tokenRefreshURL
        }

        if currentTrackId.count != 0 {
            configuration.playURI = "spotify:track:\(SpotifyManager.currentTrackId)"
        } else {
            configuration.playURI = ""
        }

        let manager = SPTSessionManager(configuration: configuration, delegate: shared)
        return manager
    }()

    static var appRemote: SPTAppRemote = {
        let appRemote = SPTAppRemote(configuration: configuration, logLevel: .debug)
        appRemote.delegate = shared
        return appRemote
    }()

    static var currentTrackId = ""

    static func play(track_id: String) {
        currentTrackId = track_id
        SpotifyManager.playerStateDidChange?()
        if sessionManager.session == nil || appRemote.isConnected == false {
            let requestedScopes: SPTScope = [.appRemoteControl]
            if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
                sessionManager.initiateSession(with: requestedScopes, options: .default)
            }
        } else {
            appRemote.playerAPI?.play("spotify:track:\(currentTrackId)") { (restult, error) in

            }
        }
    }
    static func pause() {
        currentTrackId = ""
        SpotifyManager.playerStateDidChange?()
        appRemote.playerAPI?.pause { (restult, error) in

        }
    }
    static func isPlaying(track_id: String) -> Bool {
        return SpotifyManager.currentTrackId == track_id
    }
}

extension SpotifyManager: SPTSessionManagerDelegate {
    func sessionManager(manager: SPTSessionManager, didInitiate session: SPTSession) {
        NSLog("didInitiate \(session)")

        SpotifyManager.appRemote.connectionParameters.accessToken = session.accessToken
        SpotifyManager.appRemote.connect()
    }
    func sessionManager(manager: SPTSessionManager, didFailWith error: Error) {
        NSLog("didFailWith \(error)")
    }
    func sessionManager(manager: SPTSessionManager, didRenew session: SPTSession) {
        NSLog("didRenew \(session)")
    }
}

extension SpotifyManager: SPTAppRemoteDelegate, SPTAppRemotePlayerStateDelegate {
    func appRemoteDidEstablishConnection(_ appRemote: SPTAppRemote) {
        NSLog("didEstablishConnection")
        SpotifyManager.appRemote.playerAPI?.delegate = self
        SpotifyManager.appRemote.playerAPI?.subscribe { (result, error) in
            if let error = error {
                NSLog(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
        SpotifyManager.playerStateDidChange?()
    }
    func appRemote(_ appRemote: SPTAppRemote, didDisconnectWithError error: Error?) {
        NSLog("didDisconnectWithError")
        SpotifyManager.currentTrackId = ""
        SpotifyManager.appRemote.disconnect()
        SpotifyManager.playerStateDidChange?()
    }
    func appRemote(_ appRemote: SPTAppRemote, didFailConnectionAttemptWithError error: Error?) {
        NSLog("didFailConnectionAttemptWithError")
        SpotifyManager.currentTrackId = ""
        SpotifyManager.appRemote.disconnect()
        SpotifyManager.playerStateDidChange?()
    }
    func playerStateDidChange(_ playerState: SPTAppRemotePlayerState) {
        NSLog("\(playerState.track.name)")
        SpotifyManager.playerStateDidChange?()
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you write down a proper timeline of how you interact and what happens?

Comment: I switch between tracks. Click the [Katy] button, then the [Robbie] button, then [Katy] button and cycle repeats. Tracks switches correctly but in the end of the track new wrong tracks starts.

Comment: After the requested track ends a suggested track plays. Is it possible to play only requested track?

Comment: I think you need to display more complete code. it's hard to decipher what is happening from your description. Could you accidentally have >1 instance of the player? Could the player be storing multiple instances of the requested songs thus building a skewed playlist (rather than the 1 song you want)? Lots of 'what ifs' at the moment.

Comment: The question has been updated with the source